# Making particles collide with each other? Possible? (2.8)

Tags: particles, collision

So I have made what is essentially an asteroid field. I did this by making half a dozen asteroid models, and then making a large cube with a couple of ‘volume’ emitters that run for a single frame. Which then (with a couple tweaks to velocities et al) actually makes a pretty decent looking asteroid field.

However, the asteroids hit each other, and they overlap and pass through each other. I would, ideally need them to collide and bounce. (The large ones anyway, the small ones are dust effects and I don’t really care about those).

Doubly ideally, I would like to set up a scenario where when the objects collide they might ‘shatter’ or break apart in some way. But I suspect that would be significantly more complicated.

So for the main problem - is it possible to make the particles collide with each other?

I’ve tried playing with the ‘force’ settings, the self effect, and the various physics collision options, but none of them seem to do anything in this situation.

Any help?

(As an addition, it seems an addon called 'molecular' is meant to help with this, but it doesn't seem to work any more and I'm guessing it's no longer being developed)

Comment: you tried to make a object with physics enable and "self colision" checked and put this object to be emmited in particle system?

check this video and see if helps: [https://youtu.be/F8j1K-_OlH4?t=35](https://youtu.be/F8j1K-_OlH4?t=35) (in 00:35min he shows the self colision working)

Answer (score 1):

Particles collision can be achieved with the molecular addon by pyroevil. There is a 2.80 port but you may have to do some digging to find it. Version of the addon I have for Blender 2.80 is 1.0.7 but I hear a 1.0.8 is out.
Where do I hear it, do you ask?

Here: https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-moleculars-physics/521682/255

Addon here:
https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases

As for the shattering, there is a cell fracture addon provided with 2.80. I'm not sure how you'll manage to use it on particles, though.

You can try combining with the particles instance modifier. Worth giving it a shot. Or using animation nodes, maybe.

Comment: It took a lot of finding, because the original creator didn't seem to be the one who actually updated it as I guess they've quit the development now. But I have managed to hunt down a working 2.8 version of molecular so hopefully that will work.

Why doesn't Blender have this functionality? C4D and Maya have it as basic functionality in their kits, its pretty much required for any kind of 'pouring' or other creations that use a large number of objects where particles are used to simplify it. 

Unless I'm meant to use a different method in Blender, and I've made this difficult for myself?

Comment: Thanks for your update, I think that's the same link I ended up finding but I'm glad that I'm using the right one :)  I don't think fracturing is going to work on particles though, but I can keep that for just single objects that are centre-screen so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Yes it did take a while finding. Pyroevil is no longer the maintainer, now it's Pavel I think. As for fracture it will work on the objects that you use for particles render but you may have to go through them one by one, I don't know. Maybe be do a close up on one only. You can have particles emit particles too, but I'm not sure it's going to be realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your "Midlevel" value on "Displacement" node in Donut material. You have "20.70". It is too high and this is the reason of your problem. Please change value to "0.0" or "0.5" and everything will be fine ;)

Comment: How is this answer (donut) related to the question (asteriod field)? Have you confused the question?

Comment: Answer should go here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/117021